# Adding custom fields to the search and results

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the plugin "WP Search Suggest" to suggest in the search field.
Now, the plugin works good, but it only suggest and search titles.

I looked in the plugin and found this:

```
    $query_args = apply_filters(
        'wpss_search_query_args',
        array(
            's'             =>  $s,
            'post_status'   =>  'publish',
            'post_type'     =>  'movie',
        ),
        $s
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

    if ( $query->posts ) {

        foreach ( $query->posts as $post ) {
            $results[] = $post->post_title;
        }

        $results = apply_filters(
            'wpss_search_results',
            $results,
            $query
        );

        echo join( $results, "\n" );

    }
```

and I tried to add support to custom field by adding:

```
'meta_key'      =>  'somthing',
'meta_value'        =>  '$s'
```

but I didn't work, and didn't found a way to 'echo' the results because the '$query->posts' array don't hold the meta keys or values...